# angularjs and localStorage change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I store some data in the localStorage

what I want in my angularjs app is that when the data in the localStorage changed, the app rerender the app, how can I do this?

Comment: did one of these answers address your question?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is an angular localStorage module:

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

```
var DemoCtrl = function($scope, localStorageService) {

  localStorageService.clearAll();

  $scope.$watch('localStorageDemo', function(value){
    localStorageService.add('localStorageDemo',value);
    $scope.localStorageDemoValue = localStorageService.get('localStorageDemo');
  });

  $scope.storageType = 'Local storage';

  if (!localStorageService.isSupported()) {
    $scope.storageType = 'Cookie';
  }

};
```

After further thought you may need to change the module to broadcast on setItem so that you can get notified if the localStorage has been changed.   Maybe fork and around line 50:

```
localStorage.setItem(prefix+key, value);
$rootScope.$broadcast('LocalStorageModule.notification.setItem',{key: prefix+key, newvalue: value});  // you could broadcast the old value if you want
```

or in the recent version of the library the casing was changed

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('LocalStorageModule.notification.setitem',{key: prefix+key, newvalue: value});
```

Then in your controller you can:

```
$scope.$on('LocalStorageModule.notification.setItem', function(event, parameters) {
   parameters.key;  // contains the key that changed
   parameters.newvalue;  // contains the new value
});
```

Here is a demo of the 2nd option: 
Demo:  http://beta.plnkr.co/lpAm6SZdm2oRBm4LoIi1

** Updated **

I forked that project and have included the notifications here in the event you want to use this project:  https://github.com/sbosell/angular-local-storage/blob/master/localStorageModule.js

I believe the original library accepted my PR. The reason I like this library is that it has a cookie backup in case the browser doesn't support local storage.

Comment: This is a good answer, Id like to see a jsfiddle to back it up for a +1

Comment: Here you go the things we do for the +1's.  Demo link posted to answer.

Comment: I went ahead a forked the project and added the notifications.

Comment: I see a problem with this solution. It will not catch the change event if the local storage variable was changed from the same app running in a different tab, or from inspector. Since these actions will not trigger broadcast.

Comment: @UlanMurzatayev is that one of the requirements for the original question?

Comment: @lucuma I think that is one of the requirements, since the author does not specify exactly how the data in localStorage is changed, so I assume that this case should be considered too.

Comment: The answer was already accepted so I'll assume this solution worked for the OP.  If you have a better answer that handles different browser tabs which might require polling the localstorage go for it!

Comment: @lucuma please don't feel insulted. You did a great job. Probably that's my use case, and unfortunately, polling is the only option I can think of in this case.

Comment: I wasn't insulted at all. Having multiple tabs open will almost undoubtedly require polling in some form in a spa type environment.  Maybe write a new question to see what responses you get.

Comment: Thank you for this addition to localStorage module. Really simplifies a lot of things.

Comment: They changend 'LocalStorageModule.notification.setItem' to 'LocalStorageModule.notification.setitem' ----> lowercase "i" for item :) took me ages to figure that out !

Answer (score 26):

Incidentally, I've created yet another localStorage module for AngularJS which is called **ngStorage**:

**https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage**

Usage is ultra simple:

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
    x: 42
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="$storage.x = $storage.x + 1">{{$storage.x}}</button>
```

And every change is automagically sync'd - even changes happening in other browser tabs!

Check out the GitHub project page for more demos and examples ;)

Comment: the most awesome thing is `even changes happening in other browser tabs!`.

Comment: Is there a broadcast event on changes to localStorage though? I need one controller to bind on an object in localStorage that another controller is adding. If I create the binding too soon, the object doesn't exist and I get an error.

Answer (score 5):

I recently created a module allows you to simply bind a localStorage key to a $scope variable and also store Objects, Arrays, Booleans and more directly inside the localStorage.

[Github localStorage Module](https://github.com/agrublev/Angular-localStorage)

Comment: yep, it's great stuff! much more easier

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.$on("LocalStorageModule.notification.setitem", function (key, newVal, type) {
      console.log("LocalStorageModule.notification.setitem", key, newVal, type);
    });

$scope.$on("LocalStorageModule.notification.removeitem", function (key, type) {
  console.log("LocalStorageModule.notification.removeitem", key, type);
});

$scope.$on("LocalStorageModule.notification.warning", function (warning) {
  console.log("LocalStorageModule.notification.warning", warning);
});

$scope.$on("LocalStorageModule.notification.error", function (errorMessage) {
  console.log("LocalStorageModule.notification.error", errorMessage);
});
```

this event calling when using
 https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage#getstoragetype

in app config

```
myApp.config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
  localStorageServiceProvider
    .setPrefix('myApp')
    .setStorageType('sessionStorage')
    .setNotify(true, true)
});
```