# Angular.js watch localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I need to have my application "watch" (i.e. keep track of changes of the value of) a specific key in the browser's localStorage.

This can be implemented quite easily in the limited case where I'd assume localStorage is only changed from within the instance of the application. This can be for example be done through [broadcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150311/angularjs-and-localstorage-change-event), or via other simple methods.

It becomes tricky when the application needs to be of changes made to localStorage by forces outside the application instance (e.g. a second instance of the application running in a different tab of the same browser).

I've considered a range of options, but so far I found problems with all. The only thing that I can think of now is having application run a method that polls localStorage regularly, and send a signal in case any changes were made.

Does anybody have a suggested way to watch localStorage for changes to the data. Could anybody give any pointers on how to implement this polling method that I was contemplating about?

Thanks!

Ps. At the moment I'm using [angular-local-storage [Github]](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage), but I am in no way bound to this.

Comment: in an iframe on same domain, addEventListener("storage", function(e){ doStuffHereLikeTopDotPostMessage(e.key) });   http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-webstorage-20130730/#the-storage-event

Comment: There's an answer in the link you've mentioned talking about an Angular module called ngStorage that seems to do what you need.

Comment: @MichaelBenford I've had a look at that module, but as far as I can see from the readme there is no option to actually watch localstorage.

Comment: @Teisman Take a look here: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage#read-and-write-alternative-not-recommended--demo. It seems to be able to watch the entire localstorage. Don't know what are the performance implications of doing that, though.